# Magento 2: get attribute label (considering current store view)

Tags: magento2, attributes, store-view, labels

I defined for 2 different store views 2 different attribut labels:
[image]

`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();`

This is how I get the attribute Label, but this retrieves only Default Label.

I need to display the attribute label, corresponding to user's current store. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `getStoreLabel()` ,instead of `getFrontendLabel()`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick heads up for other ppl having the same problem:
`$_product->getResource()` shouldn't be used anymore because resource models should be used directly and it's therefore deprecated.

Instead, add `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` to your constructor to use it directly.